# Side by Side Execution under .NET Framework 3.5 with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, versioning

I am having a problem related compilation of Assemblies those are running under different versions of .NET.

One assembly that is referencing some Third Party SDK must always be compiled to .NET version 4.0.  ( It's a dll ).

The other assembly ( .exe ) referencing 100 other assemblies those are compiled at 3.5 version. This assembly ( .exe ) needs to refer the above one ( .dll , which is compiled on .NET 4.0 ) and needs to include in its references as Project dependency.

What should I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just raise the version of the v3.5 project to v4 so to include the v4 dll? You could still be referencing all the v3.5 assemblies (at most with a solvable warning).

Comment: No I can't ..Because ( .EXE assembly that is referencing v4.0) referencing almost 150 binaries ( assemblies )  and in turn those referencing other assemblies ..all are compiled on .NET 3.5..
It's really impossible sort of..

Comment: @Usman: Your exe can be compiled with 4.0 and still use all those 3.5 DLLs.

Comment: But I can't compile my Exe to 4.0. The reason is that it contains almost 100 other libraries those are compiled in 3.5. I need to recompile all others as well( Because I need to make changes in the code in some of the old 3.5 compiled libraries and this forces me to compile all inter linked libraries as separate projects and then those projects would need highly coupled other assemblies as well)

So, this might not be possible for me

Comment: Why do you need to recompile the libraries? Leave them at v3.5. Is there some assembly dependent from this v3.5 exe?

Comment: Becaause v3.5 Process ( EXE ) needs to reference indirectly a library that is using some ThirParty Components those are strictly written for v 4.0

Comment: Do only the v3.5 exe or both the exe and the v3.5 libraries need to reference the v4.0 dll?

Comment: So if it's only the exe that references the v4.0 dll and not the libraries what is the problem in changing the exe project version to v4.0?

Comment: You can compile your .EXE with .NET Framework 4.0 and still reference 3.5 assemblies.